# How to delete rows of tsv

Tags: python, csv

```
1 7 c

5 2 q

4 5 a

5 0 c
```

```
for i,line in enumerate(read_tsv):
first = read_tsv[i][0]
second = read_tsv[i][1]
letter = read_tsv[i][2]
if i == 2:
```

I have a tsv file and I'd like to delete the rows where the 3rd values are not c. So I'd like it to look like this. So far I know how to seperate the values I just don't know how to delete the row based on the third tabbed value.

```
1 7 c 

5 0 c
```

Comment: You'll need to write code for that, which (based on what you have posted) you have not even attempted to do yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open the doc read/iterate it and filter out the unwanted rows then open it in write and write that data back

```
import csv

with open('filename.tsv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    data = [row for row in reader if row[2] == 'c']

with open('filename.tsv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Comment: Beware that this will overwrite the data in `filename.tsv`. Use a different filename if you want to keep the original file.

Comment: Good point I figured by OPs question that this was the desired functionality

Comment: tried it with awk but ended up using this script. thanks!